# I have the phrase words but I donot know which words shall i insert to get my wallet back , what shall I do?

Tags: wallet, trust

Trust wallet
I have my 12 phrase but I am not able to get my trust wallet back

Comment: I do not know what which word shall insert first

Comment: We're going to need some more information. What site/software? What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: the phrase has the words in the correct order already

Answer (score 0):

You insert all of them in the order you wrote them down - assuming that is the same as the order they were shown to you by the wallet when you wrote them down.

See https://community.trustwallet.com/t/how-to-restore-a-multi-coin-wallet/43

> Step 1 - Launch Trust Wallet
> Open Trust Wallet and then tap on Settings.
>
> Step 2 - Access Wallets
> In the Settings screen, you will find here Wallets. Tap on it to display the wallets that you currently have. Tap on the “+” sign on the upper right to access the Import Screen.
>
> Step 3 - Access Wallet Import Screen
> Since we are trying to restore a wallet, select I already have a wallet. Then, tap on Multi-Coin Wallet.

If you don't want a multi-coin wallet it appears you can just select Bitcoin.

> Step 4 - Input the Recovery Phrase
> Almost done. Carefully type the recovery phrase, put in the name of the wallet. Tap on Import.

> [image: phrase input screen]